# For loop only loops 1 time - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to make a for loop which will automatically add "dots" depending on how many images there are, i use the myArrImg.length but it only outputs a li with a class of dots once even tho it should do it four times? can anyone help me :)

```
var myArrImg = ['img/erftdgdf33.jpg','img/iajdi89.jpg','img/isdkfj01.jpg','img/wergf43.jpg'];

function dotsAuto(){
  var test = document.getElementById('test');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = 'dots';

  for (i = 0; i < myArrImg.length; i++) {
    test.appendChild(li);
  }
}
dotsAuto();
```

Comment: You only ever create one `li` and append it repeatedly to the same parent, thereby making it look like it only happened once. Create the `li` inside the loop.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Why didn't you post this as answer instead ? Just to get likes ? This is an answer, you'll still get them

Comment: @FREEZE tbh I'm not sure. Somewhere in the last few months I kind of stopped answering most questions fully and just posted comments to simple ones like this. Like... questions that aren't particularly helpful to people at large, or maybe I'm being too judgmental? I don't know. At 211k reputation, why would I need more? XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not what you think. The loop is operating the right number of times, but it is not doing what you intend.

The problem is that you only ever create one `li` element. You then repeatedly  insert **that same element**. So the browser thinks you are doing this:

> Create an `li` element. Give it a `className`. Now, start looping through the `myArrImg` array. On the first time, insert that `li` element. On the second time, insert that `li` element. On the third time, insert that `li` element. And so on.

You need to create new `li` elements each time, because any element can only exist once in the document. Essentially, you keep removing the element from the document and putting it back in the same place To create new elements each time, create the `li` within the loop:

```
var li;

for (i = 0; i < myArrImg.length; i++) {
  li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = 'dots';
  test.appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I created an ul since JSFiddle doesn't allow to manipulate document, but the process is the same

```js
var myArrImg = ['img/erftdgdf33.jpg','img/iajdi89.jpg','img/isdkfj01.jpg','img/wergf43.jpg'];

function dotsAuto(){
  var test = document.getElementById('test');


  for (i = 0; i < myArrImg.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.className = 'dots';
      li.innerHTML = myArrImg[i];
   test.appendChild(li);
  }
}
dotsAuto();
```

```html
<ul id="test">

</ul>
```

Basically you create ONE li for EACH loop cycle, and then append it to the list